# How to rename fragments and all in Bottom Navigation Views Activity

Tags: android-studio

The Bottom Navigation Views Activity of the new project options in Android Studio provides a nice base infrastructure for an app. The problem is, that the names of the fragments are all over the place, namely 'Home', 'Dashboard' and 'Notifications'. These names are found in layout, packages, ids, classes and so on.

Is there an easy way to rename this all to my liking?

Of course, I could do it all by hand. I'd rather not though.

Or I could simply leave it as it is and only change the strings the user actually sees. But I simply don't like that solution either.

Or maybe these new project activities aren't meant to base an actual app on, but just to showcase some functionality. New apps are meant to be based on an Empty or No Activity. Is this the case?